# Under condition $2x^2 + y^2= 4$ for real numbers $x, y$, find the maximum and minimum value of $4x + y^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, quadratics, maxima-minima, discriminant

How can I solve this problem. I can find absolute maximum and minimum value of equation with given interval. But here, I don't know where should I start. Could you explain step by step?!

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem. You need to tell us more about what you know and what you’re allowed to use in order for someone to give you a method that you’ll understand. For instance, what is the course you’re taking (or book you’re reading) in which this exercise came up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $4x+y^2=k$.

Thus, $$2x^2-4x+k-4=0,$$ which gives
$$4-2(k-4)\geq0$$ or
$$k\leq6.$$
The equality occurs for $x=\frac{4}{2\cdot2}=1$ and $y=\sqrt{2},$ which says that $6$ is a maximal value.

In another hand, since $-\sqrt2\leq x\leq\sqrt2,$ we obtain:
$$4x+y^2=4x+4-2x^2=2(3-(x-1)^2)\geq2(3-(-\sqrt2-1)^2)=-4\sqrt2.$$
The equality occurs for $x=-\sqrt2$ and $y=0,$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Comment: 4-2(k-4)≥0 where did you get it? How to remove x^2

Comment: @London Jack It's $\frac{\Delta}{4}\geq0,$ where $\Delta$ it's a discriminant of the quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1):

$$4x+y^2=4x+4-2x^2=4-2(x-1)^2+2\le4+2$$

Answer (score 1):

You want to optimize the expression $$4x+y^2$$ subject to the condition that $2x^2+y^2=4.$ In this case it is easy to just substitute for $y^2$ in the objective function to have $$4x+(4-2x^2).$$ This is a quadratic in one real variable which I'm sure you know how to optimize by completing the square. This will give you a maximum value of $6.$

Answer (score 0):

$4x+y^2=4x +4-2x^2=$

$4+ 2x(2-x);$

Constraint:

$2x^2=4-y^2$;

$x_{1,2} =\pm \sqrt{2-y^2/2}$

$4-y^2 \ge 0$; or $|y| \le 2$; and

$-√2 \le x \le √2$.

Max & Min of

$Y:=4+4x-2x^2=$

$ -2(x^2-2x)+4= -2(x-1)^2+6$;

$\max (Y _x)= 6$; (cf. lab bhatthachargee).

$\min (Y_x)$ :

The parabola $Y=-2(x-1)^2 +6$ has vertex at $(1,6)$, and is opening downward.

Since  $-√2 \le x \le √2$, we find

the minimum at the boundary point:

$x=-√2$:

$\min Y_x=-2(-√2-1)^2+6$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Write the condition as 
$$\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{y^2}{4}=1$$
with $x=\sqrt{2}\cos t$ and $y=2\sin t$ we have
$$4x+y^2=6-4\left(\cos t-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here's a graphical approach, for a different perpsective.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**:

- Step 1. Re-write your equation as $y=f(x)$.
- Step 2. Find the derivative of $f(x)$.
- Step 3. Check where this derivative is $0$ and where it is positive and negative.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I am asked to find max and min value of 4x+y^2 . Should i rewrite this equation?